# Customize Redirection of wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to redirect a wordpress site to new one. but only posts. not wp-admin.
and also should not redirect pages which start with ? on root level.
examples:

```
old.com/post-url >>>> new.com/post-url
old.com/wp-admin  >>> Not change
old.com/?custom-function >> not change.
```

Answer (score 0):

You look for something like that?

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] !== 'new.com' && is_single()) {
    $url = 'new.com'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header('Location: '.$url);
}
```

Comment: I upvoted this because it is a valid answer to the question as written and appreciate the effort.